# Bluetooth Connection: insecure connections, secure connections, listening securely or insecurely, what to use?

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I'm struggling with getting consistent bluetooth connections in a star topology. I have one master phone which is a Samsung Galaxy S4 running API 10. All of the phones that connect to the bluetoothserver socket on the S4 are LG Dynamic Tracfones also running API 10.

Over the past few days, I have seen a LOT of conflicting information on the web about what type of connection to use.

This is my current set up:

**MASTER CODE**

```
public void acceptConnection() {

.... (enable bt adapter) ...

    // initializes a Bluetooth server socket
    bluetoothServerSocket = bc.createBluetoothServerSocket();
    //connection made to Master, discovery no longer needed
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;

    // loops until the thread is interrupted or an exception occurs
    while (!isInterrupted()) {

        try {
            // attempts to accept the slave application's connection
            bluetoothSocket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // prints out the exception's stack trace
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("Default Thread", "Connection to slave failed.");
            // breaks out of the while loop
            return;
        }

        try {
            ... (enumerate all input and output streams, and all bt sockets) ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // prints out the exception's stack trace
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the method that is called when creating a blueToothServerSocket, and this is where half of my confusion is. How should I listen on the adapter? Currently, I'm doing it insecurely.

```
public BluetoothServerSocket createBluetoothServerSocket() {

    // gets the name of the application
    String name = "PVCED";
    // gets a common UUID for both the master and slave applications
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("23ea856c-49da-11e4-9e35-164230d1df67");

    // initializes an empty Bluetooth server socket
    serverSocket = null;

    try {
        // creates a Bluetooth socket using a common UUID
        serverSocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, uuid);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // prints out the exception's stack trace
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return serverSocket;
}
```

**SLAVE CODE**

And this is where the other half of my confusion is, how should I create a socket? Currently I'm doing it insecurely.

```
private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices) {

    // gets a common UUID for both the master and slave applications
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("23ea856c-49da-11e4-9e35-164230d1df67");

    // initialises an empty Bluetooth socket
    BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;

    // checks to see if there are any paired devices
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        // loops through each paired device
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            // checks to see if the name of the paired device is MASTER
            if (device.getName().equals("MASTER")) {
                try {
                    master = device;
                    // creates a Bluetooth socket using a common UUID
                    //bluetoothSocket = master.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                    //Method m = master.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] {int.class});
                    //bluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(master, 1);
                    bluetoothSocket = master.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    Log.v("Connect Exception", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //check if we paired succesfully to a master, if not, prompt user to do so.
    if (master == null){
        ... (tell user to pair with master via toast) ...
    }

    return bluetoothSocket;
}
```

My logcat is often filled with errors such as "Bad File Descriptor", "Unable to start Service Discovery", or "Service Discovery has failed."

What is the best connection scheme to use for my scenario? If you guys need more details on how I'm enabling/disabling bt adapters, or closing bt connections, I can supply more code.